# Return Gameobject to original position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I am using Unity for my project. What I am trying to do is when a button is pressed it moves a game object to a new position. Then when the same button is press again, the object returns to its original position.

My problem is with the while loop I am using; it just crashes Unity when I press this button. Am I using the while loop wrong or is there a better way of going about this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public Gameobject TroubleMove;
public Gameobject TroubleAnchor;
public Gameobject TroubleMain;
public Gameobject CauseMain;
public Gameobject Cause;
public int OnOff = 1;

public void Change ()
{
    switch (OnOff)
      {
         Case 1:
          CauseMain.setActive (true);
          Cause.setActive (true);

          While (CauseMain == true)
            {
              CauseMove.transform.position = CauseAnchor.tranform.position; 
            }
            OnOff += 1;
           break;

          Case 2:
           CauseMain.setActive (false);
           Cause.setActive  (false);
           OnOff _=1;
           break;

      }
}
```

Comment: what actually you want to do? please provide complete code. where change is calling?

Comment: I was able to figure it all out. That was the complete code by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume CauseMain is never being set to false and your while loop never exits.

Why do you need the while loop? Don't you want to change the cursor once? I would change while to if()

Comment: I am using the OnClick () command in Unity so when the button is pressed once CauseMain is set the True and then when presses again, CauseMain turns to false. See the object moves to the anchor point when CauseMain is to to true. I want it to go back to its origin position. When the button is pressed again and CauseMain goes to false.

Comment: Your OnClick() command code is missing. I cannot check if the logic you are saying is correct. Since you want it to go back to its origin position once (not multiple times) you should use an if statement instead of a loop

Comment: The OnClick Function is a prefab function that Unity includes on its gameobjects. I just attach my script my to an empty Gameobject then attach the gameobject to the OnClick (). That way I dont have to write my own OnClick.

Comment: If everything you are saying is true there is no issue. Please utilize a debugger. Please try changing while to if(), if the program doesn't break, your while loop is the problem. If it does break your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the Change() is called in the OnClick() method.

Firsly, you should not use a while(true) loop when waiting for a user input or response. The while(true) loop will become a never ending loop and crash Unity / Device.

I am confuse with what your GameObjects really are but instead of while(true) loop, you should be using the Update() or FixedUpdate() method to transform the position (can be in relation to Time.DeltaTime). If I am not mistaken, this would be the skeleton of what could be done:

```
void Update () {
    if(CauseMain) {
       //TODO: Apply Transformation Changes
       CauseMove.transform.position = CauseAnchor.tranform.position;
       CauseMain = false;
    }
}
```

This code snippet will only apply the transformation change whenever the player presses a button and once the position is set to "CauseMove", the check is disabled preventing an endless loop which will crash Unity.